# email in Hebrew is written in gibberish (mailbox)

Tags: python, hebrew, mbox

I am trying to open a email that is probably written in Hebrew:

```
print(massage.get_payload()[0].get_payload()[0].get_payload())
```

and the resulting text is gibberish. for example, here is a short segment out of it:

```
=EE=E1=F7=F9=E9=ED
```

1. how can I turn it into actual language?
2. I don't really understand the structure of the massage - when I get the payload, there is an iterable inside, and I can get the payload of each of the elements - and they are iterable themselves. what's going on here?